# Force mac to show at least two updates using softwareupdate -l

Tags: terminal

Basically I need the command `softwareupdate -l` to show at least 2 updates. I been downloading older versions of Xcode and Xcode command-line tools and so far I only managed `softwareupdate -l` to show 1 update required (Xcode command-line tools) and I need at least 2.

**MacOS version**: 10.15 Beta (19A471t).

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: If there’s only one update available, what do you propose the software do to show this “second” update?

Comment: IIWY, I would d/l and install macOS Catalina 10.15.3 first!

Comment: @Allan First of all thanks for the edits. I just need softwareupdate -l to show two updates of whatever software of package.

Comment: @klanomath going to try that, maybe it will show 2 updates, who knows. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need 2 random updates? This feels like an XY problem.

Comment: @At0mic Testing software that allows you to control PCs/MACs/anything from a server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that `softwareupdate` is only going to show you the most recent update. It wants to update you from what you have to what's current, and it doesn't show other updates that might have happened in between.

If you want to download past versions of Xcode, you should go to Apple's developer site, where every version of Xcode since version 3.0 in 2007 is available. If you have a developer account, you can get them at http://developer.apple.com/download/more/. If you don't currently have a developer account, you can sign up for free at https://developer.apple.com/programs/

Comment: I been downloading a lot of stuff from http://developer.apple.com/download/more/ trying to somehow make softwareupdate -l show 2 updates are avaiable. I dont particularly need them to be from Xcode, I just need 2 random updates on softwareupdate -l. Thanks for the replay!